# Redirect Woocommerce my-account page to another page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, account

I want to display a custom wordpress page at the "my-account" page. (Only display it if the user is logged in).

if user is not logged in, it should show the standard Login / Register. That's ok.

Right now, the my-account page, after logging in, shows the standard "From your account dashboard you can view your recent orders, manage your shipping and billing addresses and edit your password and account details." message.

I don't want that. I want users to land on a completely different wordpress page if they are logged in and visit "my-account".

Thanks,
Jo

Comment: You can just edit a current template...

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Comment: Remove the short code [woocommerce_my_account] and it becomes a blank page. You can add redirects to your functions file with hooks to check if a user is logged in or not before displaying a page.

Comment: I want to keep the Login / Register, it's ok. If I remove the [woocommerce_my_account], users won't be able to login or register

Comment: The simplest way should be to use the `myaccount/dashboard.php` template that is mostly empty to add your custom content instead…

Comment: Loic you are the best. That's what I did but it didn't look pretty, so I thought it's not the right way to do it. But now I found the mistake. A bad character in it. the php do shortcode works. I did not know php should not include the ' character in it. What to use instead when you want to include ' in php?

Comment: @Josione Update your question adding at the end an **"EDIT:"** with your actual code (shortcode + templates changes (if any) ) + the details about… With that I could answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new shortcode for that.

```
<?php 
add_shortcode('woocommerce_my_account_custom','woocommerce_my_account_custom');
function woocommerce_my_account_custom(){
if (!is_user_logged_in()) return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]');
else {
$custompage=get_post(ANOTHER_PAGE_ID);//different page ID which contains custom data for logged in users
echo apply_filters('the_content',$custompage->post_content);
}
}
```

And then replace [woocommerce_my_account] shortcode with [woocommerce_my_account_custom].

Comment: Won't this effect other functions?

Because then, when a user is logged in and wants to edit his account at my-account/edit-account/  (linked to from another page)

will it still work? because [woocommerce_my_account] would be disabled because user is logged in and it does the redirect, in the way you suggested

Comment: You can improve my function if it affects edit page.

Comment: For example you can add 'or strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"edit")!==false' condition to the first if()

Comment: Too complicated for me, I don't even know how to create shortcodes yet. I noticed the "From your account dashboard you can view your recent orders, manage your shipping and billing addresses and edit your password and account details." message is in **dashboard.php**  Can't i just edit that dashboard php so it redirects to a custom url? How to?

Comment: You can,  but it also needs to write conditional PHP code. So it seems you need to hire someone to do that

Comment: It's possible for a bit,  i can include the normal blog page in the same style by just using <?php echo do_shortcode('.............'); ?> and putting it in the dashboard.php

Where the ...... are i put my visual composer shortcodes, for example [vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text] and so on.

It works, but some part of the content does not get properly displayed. I have to think about that and find a solution if nobody can help... I thought a simple php url redirect in the dashboard to the wordpress page would work, but i don't know the code...